# VSCode: how to disable the validation of launch.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, static-analysis

Here is my `launch.json` file in VSCode:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Arquivo Atual",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Debug Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "test",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "python": "${command:python.interpreterPath}", //Property python is not allowed.
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The commented line appears as a problem. I want to disable it,  so my code have zero problems.

I believe it is a VSCode bug (already opened a issue), because it isn't marked as a problem in the first item, and if I change for the accept atribute of  `pythonPath` the debugger does not work.

How do I disable the problem message just for this file?